# Why there isn't lexicographically smallest solution to a bounded linear program?

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, computational-geometry

I am learning computational geometry when I run into this confusion. "A bounded 2D linear program may not have a lexicographically smallest solution", as the book says. I wonder why? I think we can always choose an "optimal vertex" from the feasible region based on either x-coordinates or y-coordinates.

Can anyone provide an example where a 2D LP that is bounded, but no lexicographically smallest solution?

Thanks

Comment: What’s the book’s definition of LP? Does it allow strict inequalities maybe?

Comment: What about an LP with an infinite number of constraints? The feasible region can still be bounded, but there may be no optimal or lexicographically smallest solution.